# How to dump sinatra rack test exceptions to console?

Tags: rspec, sinatra, rack

While I develop, I would like to see sinatra app exceptions when running tests, cosider example:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class ExceptionWeb < Sinatra::Base
  enable :raise_errors
  enable :dump_errors
  configure do 
    enable :dump_errors
  end
  get "/" do
    raise "hell"
    "ok"
  end
  def self.bad_method
    raise "bad method"    
  end
end


require 'rack/test'

describe 'The Web interface' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    ExceptionWeb
  end
  it "should error out" do
    get "/"
    #puts last_response.errors
    #ExceptionWeb.bad_method
    #last_response.should be_ok
  end
end
```

Following rspec code shows no exceptions at all, if I uncomment last_response, then I see something is wrong, but I don't see what was wrong.

But calling `mad_method` shows me exception.

And adding `puts last_response.errors` to every test doesn't look proper.

I tried sinatra config options `raise_errors` and `dump_errors` but that doesn't help me much.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is combination of options that must be used and then it works.

```
set :raise_errors, true
set :dump_errors, false
set :show_exceptions, false
```

Answer (score 14):

Sinatra will behave the way you want it to by default when `ENV['RACK_ENV']` is set to `'test'`. Because of the way Sinatra works, you have to make sure this environment variable is set correctly *before* the interpreter loads the file in which your application is defined (i.e. it checks this when it creates the app class, not on each request.)

Comment: Thanks! It work for me, I just run rspec like - 'RACK_ENV=test bundle exec rerun -cx rspec'. And backtrace of exception in nicely present in  terminal

Comment: Yes! I just put `ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'` at the top of my `test_helper.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something with rspec `config.backtrace_clean_patterns`? There is link about it http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/28/rspec-backtrace-filtering/

Comment: No, that's not it.rspec can show full back trace with -b option, but I don't get exception from Sinatra at all, what to speak of back trace.